# Attributed title for UIButton .selected state overrides all other states?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, title, nsattributedstring

I have 3 buttons, I want the currently selected button to have a colored underline. When I set the UIButton's attributed title for the selected state, it shows properly when selected, but then when it is unselected, it remains underlined. I then tried setting attributed strings for both `.selected` and `.normal`, one with the underline and the other one without, then the selected button does not show up at all/flashes for a second then disappears.

```
let selectedAtts: [String : Any] = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
    NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: UIColor.magenta]
let normalAtts: [String : Any] = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue]

for button in buttonList {
    let selectedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (button.titleLabel?.text)!)
    selectedText.addAttributes(selectedAtts, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: selectedText.length))
    let normalText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (button.titleLabel?.text)!)
    normalText.addAttributes(normalAtts, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: normalText.length))

    button.setAttributedTitle(normalText, for: .normal)
    button.setAttributedTitle(selectedText, for: .selected)
}
```

Has anyone encountered this and understand why it is happening?

Comment: When you tap on a button, could you check each button `state` (`UIControlState`)? I think that's where is your issue, or at least what you do exactly if you change them manually.

Comment: @Larme the two non-selected buttons .isSelected come up as false, but display the .selected state font.